# delete volumes from images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-container

When I create a container from `docker-compose` with some `volumes` and then commit that container, the `volumes` in the docker-compose file will be committed too. There is a way to not commit the volumes in the image?

With below command just can add volume but not delete them:

```
docker commit -c 'VOLUME /foo' container_name image_name
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Update (April 2018): In "[How can I edit an existing docker image metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42316614/6309)", [Guido U. Draheim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319089/guido-u-draheim) proposes [`gdraheim/docker-copyedit`](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-copyedit), a python scripts which can edit docker image metadata.

That can remove or overrides image metadata, including volumes.

The command would be:

```
./docker-copyedit.py FROM image1 INTO image2 REMOVE ALL VOLUMES
```

---

Since 2018, the same issue [now includes](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3465#issuecomment-747953796) (from [Aalex Gabi](https://github.com/aalexgabi)):

> For building a CI image with an embedded MySQL database snapshot I ended up using this solution: "[Persist & share dev data in a Docker image with `commit`](https://medium.com/@stevenlandow/persist-share-dev-mysql-data-in-a-docker-image-with-commit-f9aa9910be0a)" from [Steven Landow](https://github.com/stevenctl/Resume.md).

```yaml
FROM mysql:5.7

ADD snapshots/default.sql /tmp/default.sql

# Using separate data folder outside of mysql image declared volume
# https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3465
# https://medium.com/@stevenlandow/persist-share-dev-mysql-data-in-a-docker-image-with-commit-f9aa9910be0a
RUN mkdir /var/lib/mysql-no-volume

RUN set -exu ;\
 MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root docker-entrypoint.sh --datadir /var/lib/mysql-no-volume &\
 MYSQL_PID=$! &&\
 timeout 22 bash -c 'until printf "" 2>>/dev/null >>/dev/tcp/$0/$1; do sleep 1; done' localhost 3306 &&\
 mysql -proot -e 'create database `mydb` collate "utf8mb4_general_ci"' &&\
 mysql -proot mydb < /tmp/default.sql &&\
 kill $MYSQL_PID &&\
 tail --pid=$MYSQL_PID -f /dev/null # Using tail to wait for PID to end https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427115/listen-for-exit-of-process-given-pid

# Using separate data folder outside of mysql image declared volume
# https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3465
# https://medium.com/@stevenlandow/persist-share-dev-mysql-data-in-a-docker-image-with-commit-f9aa9910be0a
CMD ["--datadir", "/var/lib/mysql-no-volume"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is currently not possible, though there are many people requesting the feature and someone might be working on it. This Github issue discusses the topic:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3465

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit drastic but allows someone to redefine everything from scratch, as the workaround implies.

```
FROM <your image full of unwanted settings> as source

FROM scratch 

COPY --from=source / /
```

This will remove EVERYTHING, you will have to expose again environments, ports, volumes, entrypoints, commands and whatever you would like to expose.