# Changing authorship and message on existing docker commit

Tags: docker

Can we change or modify the author and message string attached to an existing docker commit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I edit an existing docker image metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42316614/how-can-i-edit-an-existing-docker-image-metadata)